# What is the dependency of 'design' in androidx?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, androidx, material-components-android

I was using Navigation Drawer there was no error by this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

But after updating in androidx

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:design:1.1.0'
```

this code not working for Navigation Drawer.

My question is what is the dependency in this situation. Please help.

Answer (score 5):

The library `'androidx.appcompat:design:x.x.x'` **doesn't** exist.
Use the [Material Component Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android):

```
//Latest beta version
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01'
```

or

```
//Latest but old stable version
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

The dependency implementation `'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha01'
```